# changing a workflow step to impersonation step

Tags: workflow, impersonation

A rather large workflow that is compromised of a single step fails for certain users since it does not run as an impersonation step. Is there a way to simply convert a step to an impersonation step? I'm afraid that if I try to simply re-write the step I will mess it up somewhere, and if I copy paste the step into a new impersonation step it creates a step within the impersonation step which I'm not entirely sure is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to a bulk copy and paste in other applications, you can hold SHIFT after selecting the first action in the original step, then click on the last one to select all of them. Then right-click to cut or copy and paste them all into your new Impersonation step. Just be sure to double-check any lookups or variable references you've set within those actions (i.e. sending emails).

Cheers,

-Drew